# Maximum Request Length Exceeded Error C# (May be Due to Session Timeout)

Tags: c#

I have built an application using Windows Forms. It compress images using threads. When I execute thread, images start compressing. All the work going well when images are in less amount. When the images are in big amount like 10,000 or more images, it throws an Exception.

### Maximum Request Length Exceeded Error.

Maybe its due to the session timeout.
All images are under 3MB.
How to resolve this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. Could you please provide your code so that we know what you've already tried as well as an example of what you're actually trying to achieve. Then I'd be happy to help

Comment: *"it throws"* - who throws? Exception typically thrown at certain line or calling a certain method. Not by "it".

Comment: Code almost has 1000 lines.

Comment: assemblies class throws exception.

Comment: As James said, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately at the moment we don't have enough information to help you. What is "assemblies class"? What exact exception is thrown? Which method call is throwing? What's compressing the images? It sounds like you need to split the request into multiple smaller requests, but we don't know what this is a request *to*.

Comment: @MuhammadNabeel we don't need ALL of your code, just the relevant sections. You essentially need to present us with a Minimum Reproducable Example. As it stands, your questions may as well read "My code doesn't work, help".